# How to add external json data into jQueryUI MultiSearch

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

According to [jqueryUI MultiSearch](http://bseth99.github.io/jquery-ui-multisearch/examples/contact.html). I'm having an issue with importing json data from the external link. The examples are only demonstrated in local data. In the example given. There're a lot of lines of sample data. I need to replace those line with an ajax json source.

**This is the example json data :**

```
localData = [
         {"display_name": "Neal, Amelia R.","organization":"XYZ Company","primary_email":"pede@nibh.com","primary_phone":"(577) 324-9152"},
         {"display_name": "Cervantes, Colton Z.","organization":"XYZ Company","primary_email":"imperdiet.dictum.magna@SuspendissesagittisNullam.com","primary_phone":"(730) 491-0518"},
         {"display_name": "Thornton, Marvin H.","organization":"XYZ Company","primary_email":"tristique@in.ca","primary_phone":"(530) 962-1617"},
         {"display_name": "Watkins, Leilani C.","organization":"XYZ Company","primary_email":"amet.massa@a.edu","primary_phone":"(368) 554-4860"}];
```

Well, as you can see. I need to replease these lines with something like this:

```
$('input').multisearch({ajax: "test.json"});
or
$.getJSON( "test.json");
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You can use `ajaxOptions`

Comment: Like this?

`$.ajax({
  url: "test.json",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});`

To be honest, I don't have any clue of jquery ajax. Please be patient to give me a lesson.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajaxOptions`, the plugin has provide options for that.

[Reference](http://bseth99.github.io/jquery-ui-multisearch/), *emphasis mine*

> **ajaxOptions**:Hash of options that are used in the $.ajax call on a remote resource. **Only used when source is a string representing the path of the resource**. Currently accepts overrides for dataType and method options.

*Example*

```
$('input').multisearch({
    source: "test.json",
    ajaxOptions: {
        searchTerm: 'term', //Your querystring parameter
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET'
    }
});
```

From [**Plugin Source Code**](http://bseth99.github.io/jquery-ui-multisearch/src/jqueryui-multisearch.js)

```
     if ( typeof( opt.source ) == 'string' ) {

        opt.ajaxOptions =
           opt.ajaxOptions || {
              searchTerm: 'term',
              dataType: 'json',
              method: 'GET'
           };

        this._remoteSearch = _.throttle( function() {

              if ( self.localCache[self.search_text] ) {
                 cb( self.search_text, self.localCache[self.search_text] );
              } else {

                 if ( self._xhr )
                    self._xhr.abort();

                 self._xhr =
                    $.ajax({
                       url: opt.source,
                       data: opt.ajaxOptions.searchTerm+'='+self.search_text,
                       dataType: opt.ajaxOptions.dataType,
                       method: opt.ajaxOptions.method
                    }).done( _.partial( cb, self.search_text ) );
              }
           },
           opt.searchThrottle,
           { leading: false }
        );
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but the original code is a bit longer than that. If you don't mind. Please try visit the source code here : http://bseth99.github.io/jquery-ui-multisearch/examples/contact.html

Comment: What code is longer? `multisearch` usage. Thats an example and I have only covered what you have asked in question.

Comment: Satpal, sorry my bad. I didn't see your embedded link. By the way, I've tried insert `$('input').multisearch({
    source: "test.json",
    ajaxOptions: {
        searchTerm: 'term', //Your querystring parameter
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'GET'
    }
});` into the script. But it is not work. Please suggest.